# Arms move in wrong direction while legs are fine

Tags: animation, rigify, pose-mode, inverse-kinematics

My model's arms bend backwards at the elbow when moving them toward the back of the character, but my legs act perfectly normally.

The only guides I've seen that seem like they might have the solution only talk about setting up a controller bone for the legs, not arms, and I can't figure out how to translate that to arms - but I'm using Rigify anyway, and the guides seem to be using the armature by itself(?) so I don't *think* controller bones are what I need as I'm not animating using the armature...?

One guide suggested that it was down to not placing a bend in the limb before generating, so I started over and tried placing a bend in the elbow in the natural direction, generated a new rig, but still had the same issue.

My legs work *great* but the arms just won't cooperate for some reason. I *would* use the FK bones(?) and just snap to those, but they twist my mesh when posed + also don't pull the mesh with them when moved - acting like objects that aren't parented - so you can only see what you've done after placing them and snapping to them which is less than optimal.

[image: snap to FK]

I've *tried* to follow any guide I can to fix the issues and make sure I'm using everything correctly, but I'm either not finding things I need, or getting confused by them when I do.

I've considered just *not* using rigify, but I'm new at this, and I don't know what the best course is that fits what I want to do. I've heard that rigify can be super useful and a good way to do things, but I've also heard of people using other methods and never touching rigify - but I don't know how they compare or what to go with based on my needs, so I've just been trying to make it work for now.

[youtube video of issue](https://youtu.be/AK4DZQs_W5o)

Comment: to be honest...if you are new...i would start using very simple rigs with two or four bones max to test and find out how it works. I wouldn't start with a human rig and i wouldn't start with an add-on if you don't know the basics at all. Why? because rigging is not intuitive and for sure not an easy topic. Of course you can start with bigger projects - but this could become frustrating....

Comment: If your rig also has "pole" bones (targets); those are the one used to control which way an elbow or knee bends when adjusting the IK for that part of the body.  In pose mode, review the bones that are incorrectly twisting, and look for a Bone Constraint IK that points to a target bone or Pole bone (the technique varies on the Rigging used) -- adjust that bone and the "twist" should correct.  If none of the problem bones has an IK or Pole target; add one.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this stuff out and let you know how I do.

How should I go about adding a pole bone for the elbow?

Comment: Rigify already has a pole target. It's hidden by default. There is a switch in the *Rigify Main Properties* section in the N-panel named "Toggle Pole" (0/1). Select the "upper_arm.IK" control bone (the big red arrow) and you should see the switch. But usually, you don't need the pole target because you can use the arrow control to rotate the upper arm. If you bend the elbow of the metarig slightly it should work out of the box => https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yv02.gif -- Maybe post a screenshot of your metarig or share the file.

Comment: @Blunder thanks! I managed to get it to work. I don't know what I missed when I tried redoing the rig before. In moving the elbows back, though, the bones ended up a little further back than I feel they would be IRL - do you know if there's any limit to avoid there? Like, "stay inside the mesh", perhaps? Also is it good to put bends in the mesh as well, or should that be straight and the bend only in the bones?

For anyone else having issues reading this - just to clarify and make things easy - I used edit mode to move the metarig's elbows back and generated a new rigify rig. Fixed.

Comment: *realised I moved them a bit far back because I had x axis mirror on and I was trying to do them individually, so I ended up moving both twice as far.

Comment: Hey, glad it's working for you. Yes, sometimes the bones can be a little misaligned compared to IRL, especially when the character is in T-pose. But usually, the rig tolerates this. An A-pose, on the other hand, is a more natural pose & the bones can better follow the mesh. Of course, you can adjust the mesh to get a better alignment. The bones just must not stick out of the mesh because the Automatic Weights don't like this. I recently had a model where I had to adjust the legs slightly because the bones stuck out of the knees & the calculated weights were really bad. The adjustment fixed it.